# Can I use javax.persistence.QueryTimeoutException with Java SE 1.6 and OpenJPA 2.1?

Tags: java, openjpa

I am using `javax.persistence.QueryTimeoutException` in my unit tests successfully with **OpenJPA 2.1** to test my code. I am using **Java 1.6** and I am not pointing to any JavaEE libs in my ant build script.

However, my customer says he can't compile because `QueryTimeoutException` is **JavaEE 6**.

How can this work for me without pointing to JavaEE.jar and not work for him? How do I separate **JavaSE 1.6** from **JavaEE 1.6** so I can reproduce this issue?

My customer didn't provide additional detail. In my unit tests, I am doing:

`import javax.persistence.QueryTimeoutException;`

and then using EasyMock like:

`EasyMock.expect(query.getResultList()).andThrow(new QueryTimeoutException("expected"));`

My java/javac version is 1.6.0_29-b11

Comment: Please provide more detail on how you are running your unit tests. `javax.persistence.QueryTimeoutException` is definitely part of JEE6.

Comment: Is it a compile error or runtime exception? If it is runtime exception provider stack-trace, and if it is compile error give more information about the class with the problem.

Comment: Are you running the tests inside eclipse or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you using for the OpenJPA lib? If you use the [openjpa-all-2.1.1.jar](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/openjpa/2.1.1/apache-openjpa-2.1.1-binary.zip), that has the javax.persistence.* APIs.

Comment: You are right. It is present in **openjpa-all-2.1.0.jar\javax\persistence\QueryTimeoutException.class**